# How to insert labels on an image and then print the page

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server

I have a aspx page, and in it put an image in a div in a 100% width and height and several label for show texts, on Visual Studio, asp.net page ...in design mode show the labels and set images for a background, but in run time don't show the texts. What should I do?
Here is my code:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #FAFAFA;
        font: 10pt "Tahoma";
    }
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .page {
        width: 21cm;
        min-height: 29.7cm;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    @page {
        size: A4;
        margin: 0;
    }
    @media print {
        .page {
            margin: 0;
            border: initial;
            border-radius: initial;
            width: initial;
            min-height: initial;
            box-shadow: initial;
            background: initial;
            page-break-after: always;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body dir="rtl">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div class="page">
         <img src="../Images/waybill-HighReso.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"/>
        <%------------------------------shipper----------------------------%>
        <div style=" z-index:1000; position:absolute;left:180px; top:58px;">
        <asp:Label ID="shipperCode" runat="server" Text="shipperCode"></asp:Label>
       </div>
        <div style=" z-index:1000; position:absolute;left:360px; top:58px;">
        <asp:Label ID="shipperName" runat="server" Text="shipperName"></asp:Label>
       </div>
        <div style=" z-index:1000; position:absolute;left:360px; top:85px;">
        <asp:Label ID="shipperTel" runat="server" Text="shipperTel"></asp:Label>
       </div>
        <div style=" z-index:1000; position:absolute;left:360px; top:105px;" >
        <asp:Label ID="shipperFrom" runat="server" Text="shipperFrom"></asp:Label>
       </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked correctly by remove attribute of body

```
<body dir="rtl">   ====> <body>
```